# Map型におけるvalueの型について

Tags: java

JAVAのMap型について質問です。

```
List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
Map<String, "文字列や数値、配列">　map = new HashMap<String, "文字列や数値、配列">();
map.put("strA", "文字");
map.put("strA", 1);
map.put("strA", array);
```

上記のように、valueにあたる部分に文字列や数値、配列が混ざったMapを作りたいのですが、どのようにすればよいでしょうか？

初歩的な質問となり大変恐縮ですが、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object`型で格納して`instanceof`で判別できます。

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sample1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("strA", "文字");
        map.put("strB", 1);
        map.put("strC", array);
        for(String key : map.keySet()) {
            Object obj = map.get(key);
            String className = obj.getClass().getName();
            System.out.println(String.format("%s の値は %s クラスです。", key, className));

            if (obj instanceof List) {
                List<String> value = (List<String>)obj;
                System.out.println(String.format("リストのサイズは %d です", value.size()));
            } else if (obj instanceof String) {
                String value = (String)obj;
                System.out.println(value);
            } else if (obj instanceof Integer) {
                int value = (int)obj;
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 上記で解決いたしました！ありがとうございました。